# Fork system call

Tags: c, fork

i tried to execute the following code in c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
int main()
{
int pid;
pid = fork ();
printf ("%d \n", pid());
           }
```

I'm getting the following result :

```
17601 
0
```

The var pid should store the value of the process id right ?!

so which of the following is the parent and which is the child's id ?! 
to be more specific i want to know what does the return value of the fork() system call ?! and why is it 0 in one of these processes ?!

another question , does this output always the same ?! or could it be inverted sometimes ?!

Kind regards

Comment: Read The Friendly Manual. 0 is the child, because the child can call getpid to identify itself, but the parent needs a handle to its child.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Please RTFM here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html before posting to SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because reading documentation "is good for you!" <tm>.

Comment: As by the nature of asynchronicity the order of the output indeterminate.

Comment: BTW, `fork()` returns `pid_t` not `int`.

Comment: BTW^2, this `..., pid());` won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

[fork(2):](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon successful completion, fork() shall **return 0 to the child**
>   process and shall return the **process ID of the child process to the
>   parent** process. Both processes shall continue to execute from the
>   fork() function. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned to the parent
>   process, no child process shall be created, and errno shall be set to
>   indicate the error.

Here's perhaps a little more illustrative example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork ();
    printf ("returned=%ld from %ld\n", (long)pid, (long)getpid());
}
```

which may give you outputs such as:

```
returned=22231 from 22229
returned=0 from 22231
```

Notice that `fork()` returns [pid_t](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html):

> The implementation shall support one or more programming environments
>   in which the widths of blksize_t, pid_t, size_t, ssize_t, and
>   suseconds_t are **no greater than the width of type long**.

The highlighted parts implies that `pid_t` can be printed with stdio through a cast to `long`, like in my example.

It's unspecified whether the child or the parent runs first. They may even run simultaneously, so the lines can be inverted, and in very rare cases where you have signal handlers installed and they get invoked, even intermingled (but such a situation would be hard to trigger).

Comment: thanks @PSkocik , so what you are saying is that in my example the number 17601  is actually  the child process id that the fork() call returned in the parent right ?!  so the output is :

<child_id> then 0  and is it always in the same order ?!

Comment: C'mon, if linking docs link to "good" ones. As `fork()` is POSIX why not use the related docs: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html

Comment: @WissamAJackal See the edited answer.

Comment: @PSkocik thanks a lot mate ! now it is clear